# Finding voltage drop on a resistance using mesh analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, network

How to find out Vx on the specified resistance using mesh analysis?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0bSXn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here **Vx** is to be found out on the **1 ohm resistor**.

I tried solving it by applying super mesh on the 5A source.I got 3 equations corresponding to the loops.

```
10*i1 - 11*i2 + 22*i3 - 5 = 0 ----- belongs to the loop containing 5V source
10*i1 - 16*i2 + i3 = 0 ----- belongs to the loop that doesn't have any source
i1 - i3 + 5 = 0 ---- supermesh
```

The solutions that I got:

```
i1 ~ 3.28A
i2 ~ 1.943A
i3 ~ -1.718A
Vx ~ 3.661V
```

But the solutions specified are:

```
i1 ~ 3.825A
i2 ~ -1A
i3 ~ 0.375A
Vx ~ 1.375A
```

Can somebody please tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: Where is polarity defined for Vx? If we assume -ve  is the right side , what is that voltage? or using mesh current from 5A Then once Ix is known Vx is known.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 The polarity is + on the left end of 1 ohm and - on the right end of 1 ohm.

Comment: as I expected... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis#Supermesh  show your loop directions and designations on schematic

Comment: . There are 5 loops to choose from.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 we need to work on 3 of the 5 loops. Right? I worked on the (5V source - 10 ohm- 1 ohm-4 ohm-17ohm) loop,  (10 ohm -5 ohm - 1 ohm) loop and the current source calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3kl0i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assume clockwise direction for all currents in the schematic.

Using KCL: $$I_2 + 5 = I_4$$

For the meshes we get:

```
10*I2 - 16*I3 +  1*I4 =  0    -----     Loop with no sources
10*I2 - 11*I3 + 22*I4 =  5    -----     Loop with 5V source
 1*I2 +  0*I3 -  1*I4 = -5    -----     From previous equation
```

The equations exactly match with the ones you got. On solving, I got:

```
I2 ~ -4.156A
I3 ~ -2.545A
I4 ~ +0.844A
Vx ~ +3.389V
```

All these values are correct as you can test on any simulator.